# Negative LookAhead to identify a match a text sequence

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I wanted to identify text which doesn't have any pattern following that. (From my perspective I think Negative Look ahead can be used in this case. Tried **"(.*?)(?![A-Z]+:)"** but was not able to get the result)

Example,

**Paragraph 1**: "This is a simple text. INTRODUCTION: Intro is the start of a paragraph"**

**Paragraph 2**: "This is a simple text"

**Output Expected**: I doesn't want the regex to match the paragraph1, but only match paragraph2, which doesn't have pattern **"[A-Z]+:"** following that.

Any help is appreciated.....

Comment: You could use `^(?!.*[A-Z]:).+` https://regex101.com/r/ol6j1A/1

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the `[A-Z]:` part inside the negative lookahead to assert that is does not occur at the right.

You can omit the `+` after `[A-Z]` and as there is a match only, you can also omit the capturing group.

Use `.+` to not match an empty string (but the dot does match a space)

```
^(?!.*[A-Z]:).+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ol6j1A/1)